# Can ElasticSearch stitch together a field to show matches from different parts of a field?

Tags: elasticsearch, highlighting

When performing a query on a long field, ie. `Description`, the field itself may be day 200 or more characters in length.

To show relevancy in a search result, can ES stitch together different parts of the field to show this?

For example:

> There was a red car with four doors driving down the brick road ... and another red balloon was floating.

If the query searches for '**red**', is there a way of displaying something like the following:

> There was a [em]red[/em] car with four doors . . . and another [em]red[/em] balloon was floating.

I realize that we can use `highlight`ing to wrap the matching keyword fragments in emphasis tags.

I would like to know if ES can stitch together the relevant field fragments around the matched keyword fragments.

Comment: That would require ES to have quite sophisticated syntax parser, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're on the right path, that's exactly what [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html) is for. Let's try it on your example.

First, let's create an index `highlights` with a mapping type having a single string field called `content`. For this example, we use the [fast vector highlighter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#fast-vector-highlighter), which does the job for what we want to show.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/highlights -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "highlight": {
      "properties": {
        "content": {
          "type": "string",
          "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then we index a new document with the content you suggested:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/highlights/highlight/1 -d '{
    "content": "There was a red car with four doors driving down the brick road bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla and another red balloon was floating."
}'
```

Now we can query it and highlight the term `red` like this:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/highlights/highlight/_search -d '{
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "content": "red"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "content": {
        "fragment_size": 30
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

This yields the following results:

```
{
  ...
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.06780553,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "highlights",
      "_type" : "highlight",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 0.06780553,
      "highlight" : {
        "content" : [ 
          "There was a <em>red</em> car with four doors", 
          "bla and another <em>red</em> balloon was floating" 
        ]
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Also note that the tags can be [customized and changed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#tags) to your likings, if needed.

Comment: Thanks is excellent, thank you. I have yet to try this, but looking fwd to it. Now since you just used match and not match-phrase, what would the result be when searching for 'red four floating'?

Comment: Is that where Matched Fields accomplishes? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#matched-fields